# Trimming copy/delete mysql table rows using Trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-5.7, database-internals

I am using Freeradius AAA server on Ubuntu 18 server which uses **mySQL ver 5.7.27** as DB to store entries. INNODB is being used. It have a table called **radacct** which stores users accounting /session data. To make radacct table slim and fit, a scheduled bash script runs every minute which copies all rows whose acctstoptime column is NOT NULL. (means there session is closed),  from **radacct** table to another table , after copying it deletes these entries from **radacct** table.
This part is working fine.

But is there any way I can use any method like **mysql** **trigger** to copy and then delete entries in real time as soon the **acctstoptime** gets update?

Example as soon as the **acctstoptime** updates with time (means not null) then it should copy immediately to another table and then delete this entry?

I tried below **mysql** **TRIGGER**

```
BEGIN
SET @usractstop = (SELECT count(*) from radacct where username=New.username and acctstoptime is NOT NULL);
IF (@usractstop = 1) THEN
SET @usractstopid  = (SELECT radacctid from radacct where username=New.username and acctstoptime is NOT NULL);
insert into radacct_archive select * from radacct where radacctid = @usractstopid;
DELETE FROM radacct WHERE radacctid = @usractstopid;
END IF;
END
```

**copy part is working, but on delete its showing error**

```
ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can’t update table 'radacct' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Any suggestions/advice ?
Some more info on db and table

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'radacct';"
+---------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name    | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+---------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| radacct | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |    1 |          16384 |       16384 |               0 |       212992 |         0 |        2323234 | 2019-11-05 19:06:21 | 2019-11-07 10:27:08 | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+---------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+

RADACCT TABLE:
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| radacctid           | bigint(21)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| acctsessionid       | varchar(64)      | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| acctuniqueid        | varchar(32)      | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| username            | varchar(64)      | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| realm               | varchar(64)      | YES  |     |         |                |
| nasipaddress        | varchar(15)      | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| nasportid           | varchar(15)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| nasporttype         | varchar(32)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| acctstarttime       | datetime         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| acctupdatetime      | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| acctstoptime        | datetime         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| acctinterval        | int(12)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| acctsessiontime     | int(12) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| acctauthentic       | varchar(32)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| connectinfo_start   | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| connectinfo_stop    | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| acctinputoctets     | bigint(20)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| acctoutputoctets    | bigint(20)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| calledstationid     | varchar(50)      | NO   |     |         |                |
| callingstationid    | varchar(50)      | NO   |     |         |                |
| acctterminatecause  | varchar(32)      | NO   |     |         |                |
| servicetype         | varchar(32)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| framedprotocol      | varchar(32)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |

+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
SHOW CREATE TABLE RADACCT;
| Table   | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
| radacct | CREATE TABLE `radacct` (
  `radacctid` bigint(21) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `acctsessionid` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `acctuniqueid` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `realm` varchar(64) DEFAULT '',
  `nasipaddress` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nasportid` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nasporttype` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctstarttime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctupdatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctstoptime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctinterval` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctsessiontime` int(12) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctauthentic` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `connectinfo_start` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `connectinfo_stop` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctinputoctets` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acctoutputoctets` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `calledstationid` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `callingstationid` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `acctterminatecause` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `servicetype` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `framedprotocol` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `framedipaddress` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `framedipv6address` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `framedipv6prefix` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `framedinterfaceid` varchar(44) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `delegatedipv6prefix` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`radacctid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `acctuniqueid` (`acctuniqueid`),
  KEY `username` (`username`),
  KEY `framedipaddress` (`framedipaddress`),
  KEY `framedipv6address` (`framedipv6address`),
  KEY `framedipv6prefix` (`framedipv6prefix`),
  KEY `framedinterfaceid` (`framedinterfaceid`),
  KEY `delegatedipv6prefix` (`delegatedipv6prefix`),
  KEY `acctsessionid` (`acctsessionid`),
  KEY `acctsessiontime` (`acctsessiontime`),
  KEY `acctstarttime` (`acctstarttime`),
  KEY `acctinterval` (`acctinterval`),
  KEY `acctstoptime` (`acctstoptime`),
  KEY `nasipaddress` (`nasipaddress`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2323234 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Trigger cannot perform this action. Show table's DDL (or at least specify its engine).

Comment: Does you may affect on the queries which uses this table's data (alter queries texts)?

Comment: I have updated the question with more details for table/engine type.
What is the workaround to achieve this task in real time?

Comment: `Show create table` is more informative then `show table status`. Please add or replace. *What is the workaround to achieve this task in real time?* InnoDB... hmm... Think about partitioning by `acctstoptime IS NULL`. After such partitioning you may add `WHERE ... AND acctstoptime IS NULL` into your queries, and they will not access the partition which stores the info about closed sessions. Closing session with setting acctstoptime will automatically move the record from one partition to another.

Comment: ok i have updated show create table as well.